# AWS: Connecting from virtual machine to SQL database

Tags: .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I've created a virtual machine on AWS, and I've also created a SQL Server Express instance. I now want a .NET app on the virtual machine to talk to the database.

I can connect to the instance/database via SSMS on my laptop using the details:

```
Server name: amazontest.xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Login: Administrator
Password: xxxx
```

So the instance is up & running, and is publically accessible.

In my web.config on my .net app, I have the following connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
    connectionString="Server=amazontest.xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Database=amazontest;User Id=Administrator;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But that keeps giving me an error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.`

I'm not sure what else to try, if outside connections are working...

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was in the `Security Groups`.

When you create the RDS, it assigns a security group with your **current** IP address for inbound traffic, hence why SSMS was working from my laptop. I had to edit the security group it created, adding an `Inbound` rule for the **Private IP** of the Virtual Machine.

i.e. on the VM instance, find the `Private IP` address, and add it as an `Inbound` rule to the security group, with type: `Custom TCP Rule`, Port Range: `1433`, Source: `X.X.X.X/32`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an app is not able to establish a connection with DB because of port(1433) is not open or may open for few IP so you need to whitelist your app server IP into security group of RDS instance.